# Web page looking bad after uploading on server

Tags: upload

I'd create a web page with jquery and css3 and is looking good on my computer but after upload on server is awful in IE. In any other browser everything is good.

Any suggestion why is that?

Comment: You might have forgotten to upload something, your server might not  be configured correctly, or a dozen other things might be happening. Please post a link to the page.

Comment: Are you asking us why a webpage renders different in one browser than another?

Comment: Yes - did you test your items locally using all the same browsers as after you uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your css is not "compatible" to IE. Every brother is interpreting css a little bit different.